# Recharts - Tooltip for each Bar in a Bar Chart composed of three bars

Tags: recharts

I have in my bar chart three different bars.
I would like to have a tooltip for each bar in the bar chart and not just one for the three.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'Recharts';

const data = [
  { name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 1982, amt: 2400 },
  { name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 4739 },
  { name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 9056 },
  { name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000 },
  { name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4678, amt: 2181 },
  { name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2873 },
  { name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 1987, amt: 2100 },
];

class SimpleBarChart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BarChart
        width={600}
        height={300}
        data={data}
        margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Bar dataKey="pv" barSize={20} fill="#8884d8" />
        <Bar dataKey="amt" barSize={20} fill="#82ca9d" />
        <Bar dataKey="uv" barSize={20} fill="#ffc658" />
      </BarChart>
    );
  }
}

export default SimpleBarChart;
```

Answer (score 15):

Following Natasha's answer, first create a custom tooltip:

```
<Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip/>} />
```

Add a function/component to render the custom contents.  The variable `tooltip` is used to identify which Bar is being hovered over.  The contents can be customized using the `payload` which contains all the bars in the selection.

```
var tooltip
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload }) => {
    if (!active || !tooltip)    return null
    for (const bar of payload)
        if (bar.dataKey === tooltip)
            return <div>{ bar.name }<br/>{ bar.value.toFixed(2) }</div>
    return null
}
```

Finally, add `name` and `onMouseOver` props to each `<Bar>` element:

```
<Bar dataKey="pv" barSize={20} fill="#8884d8"
     name="Name" onMouseOver={ () => tooltip="pv" } />
```

When the mouse hovers over that `<Bar>` it will set the tooltip variable to the value "pv". Then the `CustomTooltip` will find that entry in the `payload` parameter and display the name and value.

Answer (score 7):

You can add shared={false} props into Tooltip like this:

```
<Tooltip shared={false} />
```

Comment: Don't work on simple line example: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom tooltip like in the example here:

http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomContentOfTooltip <---- Customized tooltip example (from recharts documentation)

After you create a customized tooltip, you can call it in the Bar component's OnMouseOver property which is in the documentation here:

http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Bar#onMouseOver <---- OnMouseOver

You could also use OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave but I know that doesn't work for everyone.

You might want to create a function that shows the tooltip when the mouse hovers over a bar and hides the tooltip when the mouse stops hovering over the bar.